# Need to get actor name out of the Json file

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, nlp, nltk, spacy

i want to get actor name out of this json file page_title and then match this with database i tried using nltk and spacy but there i have to train data. Do i have train for each and ever sentence i have more than 100k sentences. If i sit to train data it will takes a month or more. Is there any way that i can dump K_actor database to train spacy, nltk or any other way.

```
{"page_title": "Sonakshi Sinha To Auction Sketch Of Buddha To Help Migrant Labourers", "description": "Sonakshi Sinha took to Instagram to share a timelapse video of a sketch of Buddha that she made to auction to raise funds for migrant workers affected by Covid-19 crisis. ", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589815261_1589815196489_copy_875x583.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/sonakshi-sinha-to-auction-sketch-of-buddha-to-help-migrant-labourers-2626123.html"}
{"page_title": "Anushka Sharma Calls Virat Kohli 'A Liar' on IG Live, Nushrat Bharucha Gets Propositioned on Twitter", "description": "In an Instagram live interaction with Sunil Chhetri, Virat Kohli was left embarrassed after Anushka Sharma called him a 'jhootha' from behind the camera. This and more in today's wrap.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589813980_1589813933996_copy_875x583.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/anushka-sharma-calls-virat-kohli-a-liar-on-ig-live-nushrat-bharucha-gets-propositioned-on-twitter-2626093.html"}
{"page_title": "Ranveer Singh Shares a Throwback to the Days When WWF was His Life", "description": "Ranveer Singh shared a throwback picture from his childhood where he could be seen posing in front of a poster of WWE legend Hulk Hogan.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589812401_screenshot_20200518-195906_chrome_copy_875x583.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/ranveer-singh-shares-a-throwback-to-the-days-when-wwf-was-his-life-2626067.html"}
{"page_title": "Salman Khan's Love Song 'Tere Bina' Gets 26 Million Views", "description": "Salman Khan's song Tere Bina, which was launched a few days ago, had garnered 12 million views within 24 hours. As it continues to trend, it has garnered 26 million views in less than a week.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589099778_screenshot_20200510-135934_chrome_copy_875x583.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/salman-khans-love-song-tere-bina-gets-26-million-views-2626077.html"}
{"page_title": "Yash And Radhika Pandit Pose With Their Kids For a Perfect Family Picture", "description": "Kannada actor Yash tied the knot with actress Radhika Pandit in 2016. The couple shares two kids together.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589812187_yash.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/yash-and-radhika-pandit-pose-with-their-kids-for-a-perfect-family-picture-2626055.html"}
{"page_title": "Malaika Arora Shares Beach Vacay Boomerang With Hopeful Note", "description": "Malaika Arora shared a throwback boomerang from a beach vacation where she could be seen playfully spinning. She also shared a hopeful message along with it.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589810291_screenshot_20200518-192603_chrome_copy_875x583.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/malaika-arora-shares-beach-vacay-boomerang-with-hopeful-note-2626019.html"}
{"page_title": "Actor Nawazuddin Siddiqui's Wife Aaliya Sends Legal Notice To Him Demanding Divorce, Maintenance", "description": "The notice was sent to the ", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2019/10/Nawazuddin-Siddiqui.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/actor-nawazuddin-siddiquis-wife-aaliya-sends-legal-notice-to-him-demanding-divorce-maintenance-2626035.html"}
{"page_title": "Lisa Haydon Celebrates Son Zack\u2019s 3rd Birthday With Homemade Cake And 'Spiderman' Surprise", "description": "Lisa Haydon took to Instagram to share some glimpses from the special day. In the pictures, we can spot a man wearing a Spiderman costume.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589807960_lisa-rey.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/lisa-haydon-celebrates-son-zacks-3rd-birthday-with-homemade-cake-and-spiderman-surprise-2625953.html"}
{"page_title": "Chiranjeevi Recreates Old Picture with Wife, Says 'Time Has Changed'", "description": "Chiranjeevi was last seen in historical-drama Sye Raa Narasimha Reddy. He was shooting for his next film, Acharya, before the coronavirus lockdown.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589808242_pjimage.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/chiranjeevi-recreates-old-picture-with-wife-says-time-has-changed-2625973.html"}
{"page_title": "Amitabh Bachchan, Rishi Kapoor\u2019s Pout Selfie Recreated By Abhishek, Ranbir is Priceless", "description": "A throwback picture that has gone viral on the internet shows Ranbir Kapoor and Abhishek Bachchan recreating a selfie of their fathers Rishi Kapoor and Amitabh Bachchan.", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589807772_screenshot_20200518-184521_chrome_copy_875x583.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/amitabh-bachchan-rishi-kapoors-pout-selfie-recreated-by-abhishek-ranbir-is-priceless-2625867.html"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that you can do is to create an annoter script wherein you can replace actor names with '@@@' or some other string (which will be replaced later with actor names (entities) for training).

I trained 68K data/sentences in 9 hrs with my i3 laptop. You can dump data like this and the output file can be used for training the model.

That will save time and also give you ready made training data format for SpaCy.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from pandas import read_csv
import re
import os.path


def annot(Label, entity, textlist) :
    finaldict = []
    for text_token in textlist:
        textbk=text_token
        for value in entity:
            #if entity has multi tokens        
            text=textbk
            text=text_token
            text=str(text).replace('@@@',value)
            text=text.lower()
            text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]',' ', text)
            if len(word_tokenize(value))<2:
                #print('I am here')
                newtext=word_tokenize(text)
                traindata=[]
                prev_length=0
                prev_pos=0
                k=0
                while k != len(newtext):
                    if k == 0:
                        prev_pos=0
                        prev_length=len(newtext[k])
                        if value.lower()== str(newtext[k]):
                            ent=Label
                            tup=(prev_pos,prev_length,ent)
                            traindata.append(tup)
                        else:
                            pass
                    else :
                        prev_pos=prev_length+1
                        prev_length=prev_length+len(newtext[k])+1
                        if value.lower()==str(newtext[k]):
                            ent=Label
                            tup=(prev_pos,prev_length,ent)
                            traindata.append(tup)
                        else:
                            pass
                    k=k+1
                mydict={'entities':traindata}
                finaldict.append((text,mydict))
            else:
                traindata=[]
                try:
                    begin=text.index(value.lower())
                    ent=Label
                    tup=(begin,len(value.lower()),ent)
                    traindata.append(tup)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                mydict={'entities':traindata}
                finaldict.append((text,mydict))
    return finaldict

def getEntities(csv_file, column) :
    df = read_csv(csv_file)
    return df[column].to_list()

def getSentences(file_name) :   
    with open(file_name) as file1 :
        sentences = [line1.rstrip('\n') for line1 in file1]
    return sentences

def saveData (data, filename, path) :
    filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filename, 'a') as file :
        for sent in data :
            file.write("{}\n".format(sent))

ents = getEntities(csv_file, column_name) #Actor names in your case
entities = [ent for ent in ents if str(ent) != 'nan']


sentences = getSentences(filepathandname) #Considering you have the sentences in a text file
label = 'ACTOR_NAMES'   
data = annot(label, entities, sentences)
saveData(data, 'train_data.txt', path)
```

Hope this is a relevant answer for your question.

Comment: ```File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 29 fields in line 1592, saw 37``` this what I'm getting every time.

Comment: Does this happen when you read the csv file ? When do you hit the error ?

Comment: ```csv_file = 'cast_dump.csv' 
column_name = 'name'
filepathname =  'ndtv.txt' ```
this is what i give as input then i ran the code and got this error